# Differential Equation With a Twist

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I came across this question and was trying to figure out how one would go about solving it. It has a been a long time since I had a DE class so I apologize if I am missing something simple.

$$(x^2+x)\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}-(x^2-2)\frac{dy}{dx}-(x+2)y=0$$
  Given that $y=e^x$ is a solution, what is the general solution of this equation?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE, J.Ray. This site uses [MathJax formatting of formulas](//math.stackexchange.com/help/notation). More tips [here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9959). *(from a bot)*

Answer (score 1):

$y=e^x$ is a solution
suppose $y = u e^x$ is a solution:

$y' = u' e^x + u e^x$

$y'' = u'' e^x + 2 u' e^x + u e^x$

$(x^2 + x)y'' - (x^2-2)y' - (x+2) y = 0$

$e^x ((x^2 + x)(u'' + 2u') - (x^2-2) u') = 0$

$(x^2 + x)u'' + (x^2+2x+2) u' = 0$

$u'' = -(x^2+2x+2)/(x^2+x) u'$

$u''/u' = -1 -2/x + 1/(x+1)$

$\ln u' = -x-2\ln x +\ln(x+1) c$

$u' =  C \frac{x+1}{x^2} e^x$

$u = C_1 (2 Ei(x)-e^x/x) + C_2$

$y = C_1 (2 e^x Ei(x)-e^{2x}/x) + C_2 e^x$

Comment: Why is your answer so different from the wolframAlpha link?

Comment: Because I managed to drop an x.

Answer (score 0):

Let me WolframAlpha it for you: [Link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20%28x%5E2%20%2B%20x%29%20y%27%27%20-%20%28x%5E2%20-2%29%20y%27%20-%20%28x%20%2B%202%29%20y%20%3D%200)